# Why isn't preferredContentSize used by iPhone 6 Plus Landscape?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, iphone-6-plus

In my iOS 8 app, this popover segue appears correctly on all devices in all orientations except for iPhone 6 Plus landscape:

[image: Good popover]

This is how it looks on iPhone 6 Plus landscape (it is stretching almost from top to bottom):
[image: Bad popover]

And when it displays like this, clicking outside of the view doesn't dismiss it (although Cancel does work). Rotating back to portrait gets it back to normal.

All of the constraints in this `UIViewController` are installed on all size classes.

When debugging values in `viewDidAppear:` I see the following:

- po self.view:  frame = (0 0; 250 394)
- po self.preferredContentSize  (width = 250, height = 160)

What is causing the view's height to jump to 394?

I'm actually having the same issue with another popover segue in iPhone 6 Plus landscape as well.  (And in case there was curiosity, I'm using a VC instead of 'UIAlertController' here because of the validation requirements of the `UITextField` displayed don't work well with `UIAlertController`.)

**Edit to include my popover code:**

This code is found in `prepareForSegue:`

```
    FavoriteNameViewController *nameVC = segue.destinationViewController;
    UIPopoverPresentationController *popPC = nameVC.popoverPresentationController;
    popPC.delegate = self;
    nameVC.delegate = self;
    nameVC.view.center = self.originalContentView.center;
```

And then the delegate method:

```
- (UIModalPresentationStyle)adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller {
    return UIModalPresentationNone;
}
```

And here is the segue definition in Xcode:
[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What you're seeing is not a popover. It's a normal presented view. By default, a popover appears as a popover on iPad, but as a presented view on iPhone — including the iPhone 6 plus. On other iPhones, this presented view is fullscreen - it covers everything. But the iPhone 6 is so wide that they don't do that, so it appears in the middle of the screen at a standard width (the width of a smaller iPhone).

Thus, the preferred content size has no effect. This isn't a popover. Presented view controller views are given a standard size, and this one is no exception.

However, you *can* have the popover appear *as a popover* on iPhone. To do so:

- Set a delegate for the popover view controller's `popoverPresentationController` *before* presenting it.
- In the delegate, implement `adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:` and return `.None`.

However, this is apparently not working on iPhone 6 Plus in landscape mode; the popover is not "adapting". I would describe this as a bug!

**EDIT** In iOS 9, *the problem is solved!* Implement the new delegate method `adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:traitCollection:` to return `.None` and you'll get a popover under all circumstances, including the iPhone 6 Plus in landscape. Here's a complete working example where the popover is created and summoned in code in response to a button tap:

```
@IBAction func doButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let vc = MyViewController()
    vc.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(400,500)
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    if let pres = vc.presentationController {
        pres.delegate = self
    }
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    if let pop = vc.popoverPresentationController {
        pop.sourceView = (sender as! UIView)
        pop.sourceRect = (sender as! UIView).bounds
    }
}
func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(
    controller: UIPresentationController, 
    traitCollection: UITraitCollection) 
    -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
        return .None
}
```

[image]

Comment: given the edits I added, it sounds like I'm already doing what you're suggesting.

Comment: And is that delegate method being called?

Comment: It is.  I just confirmed it in debug.

Comment: I see the problem, I think. Check one of the arrow Directions checkboxes? (Just try it and see if it helps...)

Comment: Nope, that isn't going to fix it.

Comment: I did a lot of testing and I think you've found a bug. Let me know if you're too busy to report it to Apple; I'll do it if you like.

Comment: I appreciate you looking into this.  If you don't mind, please report the bug.  Is there a link you can provide of the bug report (if it's public)?  I'm not familiar with the bug reporting process.

Comment: This bug is now fixed in iOS 9. I can't tell whether the fix is iOS 9 only or whether it works backwards all the way to iOS 8.3.

Comment: Hi Matt.  Thanks for the response, and sorry for my delay responding.  I'm a bit confused b/c your answer seems to indicate to implement a method that I already have implemented.  Maybe I'm not following what you're saying.  I'm still getting the odd appearance in landscape at iOS 9. Sidenote: this isn't an issue on iPad.

Comment: Please read _carefully_ what I said. Look _carefully_ at my code. Note please that the method I'm talking about which fixes the problem, `adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:traitCollection:`, is _not the same_ as the old `adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:` that your code shows you were implementing before. It behaves completely differently. It solves the problem, and my screen shot proves it.

Comment: Thanks, Matt.  TBH I thought I was looking at it closely, but clearly I missed it.  That method did work.  Many thanks!

Comment: Cool! Glad that took care of it. I was very pleased to see this change and that's why I reported back.

Comment: I installed the 8.1 simulator.  Looks like the old adaptive method is needed for iOS 8.0-8.2.  The 8.1 6Plus landscape simulator is working...  but as an fyi - it doesn't break on either `adaptive...` method.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. I already said this fix applies only to iOS 9 and possibly 8.3. Obviously we can't change the past: the bug in 8.0, 8.1, 8.2 does not magically vanish.